# Issue with HTML element in Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have the below Visualforce page where clicking on button I would like to fetch the value from input text and put that in alert.

Here is the VisualForce page -

```
<apex:page controller="AccountJSRemotingController" showHeader="true" showChat="true">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function search(){
            alert('INside');
            var searchText = document.getElementById('searchId').value();
            alert('SearchText: '+ searchText);
        }   

    </script>
    <h2>
        Account Search Page
    </h2>
    <br/>
    <input id="searchId" type="text" placeholder="Enter Account Name:"/>
    <input id="btnSearch" type="button" value="Search Account" onclick="search();"/>

    <table>
        <tbody id="results"></tbody>
    </table>
</apex:page>
```

I am getting the error -

> document.getElementById(...).value is not a function

Can someone please help me to understand how can I get the reference of HTML element in Visualforce page like above? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

value is a property of getElementById. its not a method.

change

```
document.getElementById('searchId').value();
```

to

```
document.getElementById('searchId').value;
```

Note : this question might get closed since it seems purely javascript related and nothing to do with salesforce.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vamsi. It is a very basic mistake from my side. Sorry my friend

Comment: no worries. happy to answer.. :-)

Comment: @SudiptaDeb you can mark this question as solved by marking Vamsi's answer as the solution. There's a (V) button on the left of the answer just below the upvotes, this will also give some additional reputation to Vamsi (as a thank you)